# Cannot find linux/sched/types.h (for RT-patched Linux kernel)

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

I am running a RT-patched Linux kernel (4.14.184-rt84) for some real-time requirements in our project. I added sheduling policy-related lines in my code (borrowed from the [source code](https://github.com/gergondet/mc_linuxrt/blob/master/src/main.cpp)) wherein the needed header files are "linux/sched.h" and "linux/sched/types.h". However, when I build it, "linux/sched/types.h" cannot be found. How do I fix this? Is there a standard way of adding these types of header files when using a RT-patched Linux? Shown below is the error that I get:

```
/home/devpc/jittertest_ros1_ws/src/jittertest/src/jittertest/jittertest_node.cpp:20:31: fatal error: linux/sched/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Edit:
As an attempt to solve this problem, I added /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-107/include to the include_directories in CMakeLists.txt, and after which, the error I have is now:

```
In file included from /home/devpc/jittertest_ros1_ws/src/jittertest/src/jittertest/jittertest_node.cpp:19:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-107/include/linux/sched.h:12:25: fatal error: asm/current.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Thanks

Comment: Userspace headers are under include/uapi, and I see include/uapi/linux/sched/types.h

Comment: uAPI headers are supplied by distributions in a separate package, usually called *linux-headers* or *kernel-headers*. That's what you are missing.